# replace multiple spaces, tabs and newlines into one space except commented text

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need replace multiple spaces, tabs and newlines into one space except commented text in my html.
For example the following code:

```
<br/>    <br>

<!--
this   is a comment

-->
<br/>   <br/>
```

should turn into

```
<br/><br><!--
this   is a comment

--><br/><br/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a very though mission using pure regex. Have you elaborated a plan so we can improve it ?

Comment: I have a plan to explode code to blocks "before-comments" and "after-comments" and regex them separately. But I would like to know if there is a chance of using pure regex.

Comment: Shouldn’t there be a space between `<br/><br/>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The *new* solution**

After thinking a bit, I came up with the following solution with pure regex. Note that this solution will delete the newlines/tabs/multi-spaces instead of replacing them:

```
$new_string = preg_replace('#(?(?!<!--.*?-->)(?: {2,}|[\r\n\t]+)|(<!--.*?-->))#s', '$1', $string);
echo $new_string;
```

**Explanation**

```
(?                              # If
    (?!<!--.*?-->)              # There is no comment
        (?: {2,}|[\r\n\t]+)     # Then match 2 spaces or more, or newlines or tabs
    |                           # Else
        (<!--.*?-->)            # Match and group it (group #1)
)                               # End if
```

So basically when there is no comment it will try to match spaces/tabs/newlines. If it does find it then group 1 wouldn't exist and there will be no replacements (which will result into the deletion of spaces...). If there is a comment then the comment is replaced by the comment (lol).

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/7wt9g5)

---

**The *old* solution**

I came up with a new strategy, this code require PHP 5.3+:

```
$new_string = preg_replace_callback('#(?(?!<!--).*?(?=<!--|$)|(<!--.*?-->))#s', function($m){
    if(!isset($m[1])){ // If group 1 does not exist (the comment)
        return preg_replace('#\s+#s', ' ', $m[0]); // Then replace with 1 space
    }
    return $m[0]; // Else return the matched string
}, $string);

echo $new_string; // Output
```

**Explaining the regex:**

```
(?                      # If
    (?!<!--)            # Lookahead if there is no <!--
        .*?             # Then match anything (ungreedy) until ...
        (?=<!--|$)      # Lookahead, check for <!-- or end of line
    |                   # Or
        (<!--.*?-->)    # Match and group a comment, this will make for us a group #1
)
# The s modifier is to match newlines with . (dot)
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/cHdNS2)

> <sub>**Note:** What you are asking and what you have provided as expected output are a bit contradicting. Anyways if you want to *remove* instead of *replacing by 1 space*, then just edit the code from **'#\s+#s', ' ', $m[0]** to **'#\s+#s', '', $m[0]**.</sub>

Comment: Try with `<!--  foo  <!--  bar  -->  baz`. (SO removes the spaces, but you'll see the bug if you add some.)

Comment: @Denis Now you're coming with an unlikely expected scenario, I didn't even try it and I know it will fail.

Comment: Pesky HTML nesting rules, heh? :-) (And yes, agreed.)

Comment: @Denis Normally I would go with the approach of matching and then replacing if needed, like you mentioned.

Comment: Per my own answer, I think the correct regex needs an ugly look-behind, rather than a look-ahead. It needs to find no occurrence of `<!--` *or* an occurrence of `-->`, which terminates an html comment irrespective of the nesting level -- everything else should be assumed to be within a comment. But then this regex will, I think, end up having backtracking problems with long text.

Comment: @Denis Indeed, but there is a problem though. PCRE doesn't support unfixed length lookbehinds, which means you can't use `(?!<foo.*?)bar`. That's why an undestructible PCRE solution is impossible.

Comment: Great, the old solution works for me. The new solution can raise errors, if there is a following code: <th  colspan="2"> - it is turned into <thcolspan="2">. @HamZa, thank you very much!

Comment: @ro_jero that shouldn't be the case for `<th colspan="2">` unless you have a newline or tab instead of space there. Take care

Comment: @HamZa there are 2 spaces between th and colspan

Comment: @ro_jero heh, unexpected :p

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler to do this in several runs (as is done for instance in php markdown).

Step1: `preg_replace_callback()` all comments with something unique while keeping their original values in a keyed array -- ex: `array('comment_placeholder:' . md5('comment') => 'comment', ...)`

Step2: `preg_replace()` white spaces as needed.

Step3: `str_replace()` comments back where they originally were using the keyed array.

The approach you're leaning towards (splitting the string and only processing the non-comment parts) works fine too.

There almost certainly is a means to do this with pure regex, using ugly look-behinds, but not really recommended: the regex might yield backtracking related errors, and the comment replacement step allows you to process things further if needed without worrying about the comments themselves.

Comment: No need to replace the comments with placeholders. Just separate them from non-comment sequences and do the space replacement only on those sequences.

Comment: **+1** For the md5 trick, now hoping that you won't have a md5 collision :p

Comment: @Gumbo: agreed on paper; in practice, it's quite useful if you want to process the text several times while keeping the html well formed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '~\s*+(<br[^>]*>|<!--(?>[^-]++|-(?!->))*-->)\s*+~';
$replacement = '$1';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

This pattern captures *br* tags and comments, and matches spaces around. Then it replaces the match by the capture group.

Answer (score 1):

I’d do the following:

1. split the input into comment and non-comment parts
2. do replacement on the non-comment parts
3. put everything back together

Example:

```
$parts = preg_split('/(<!--(?:(?!-->).)*-->)/s', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
foreach ($parts as $i => &$part) {
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        // non-comment part
        $part = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $part);
    } else {
        // comment part
    }
}
$output = implode('', $parts);
```